# Freeradius, Syntax error: Expected comma

Tags: linux, centos, alma-linux, freeradius

I'm trying to set up 2FA for a list of users.

But in the process I got an error that I can’t fix:

"/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[35]: Syntax error: Expected comma after 'check-item': {"

I checked commas, spaces and quotes.

I just can't find my mistake.

Is it possible that I wrote the config incorrectly?

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

```
    authorize {
        filter_username

        if (&User-Name) {
           update control {
                2FA_USERS := check-item {
                    filename = "/etc/raddb/users_2fa",
                    item-name = "%{User-Name}",
                    flags = case-sensitive 
                }
            }

            if (2FA_USERS) {
                filter_google_otp

                if ((ok || updated) && &Google-Password && !control:Auth-Type) {
                    update control {
                        Auth-Type := `/myhome/scripts/google_2fa.py %{User-Name} %{Google-Password}`
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        preprocess
    }
```

Solved:
[Freeradius, 2FA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773259/freeradius-2fa)