# Freeradius, 2FA

Tags: linux, centos, alma-linux, freeradius

Help me solve the problem with setting up two-factor authentication on FreeRadius.

FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.20

In general, I configured the second factor for all connecting users,

but I can’t configure it so that only certain users

should have been tested for the second factor.

Now the workflow is like this:

all users are checked for LDAP and for the second factor upon connection.

How to:

All users are verified on the LDAP server,

and users that are defined in a separate file (only their LDAP logins)
were also tested for the second factor.

Here is an example of my config that works for all users:

```
cat /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default

authorize {
    filter_username
    filter_google_otp
    preprocess

    if ((ok || updated) && Google-Password && !control:Auth-Type) {
        update control {
            Auth-Type := `/path_to_script/auth_2fa.py %{User-Name} %{Google-Password}`
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to add a check after filter_username to see if the user's User-Name
matches the user from the file.
And if this match is found, perform a test for factor 2.

if not, move on.

I really couldn’t find anything like it on the Internet.

```
 filter_username

        if (&User-Name) {
           update control {
                2FA_USERS := check-item {
                    filename = "/etc/raddb/users_2fa",
                    item-name = "%{User-Name}",
                    flags = case-sensitive 
                }
            }

            if (2FA_USERS) {
                filter_google_otp
```

Perhaps my implementation idea is not suitable.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolve:

```
    authorize {
        filter_username
        if (`/path_to_script/check_user_2fa.sh %{User-Name}`) {
            filter_google_otp
            ldap
            if ((ok || updated) && Google-Password && !control:Auth-Type) {
                update control {
                    Auth-Type := `/path_to_script/google_2fa.py %{User-Name} %{Google-Password}`
                }
            }
        } else {
            update {
                control:Auth-Type := ldap
             }

        }
        preprocess
    }
```

if successful, the script check_user_2fa.sh displays ok